# java html code genarating class

Tags: java, html, email, html-generation

I'm developing a business application using Java. I want to allow my manager to edit and send sample emails to customers, sellers, etc. I have to allow him to create an email in my application. My problem is that I have to generate HTML codes when he inserts images, bolds a particular text, highlights a text, inserts links, and so on. I realize it's not easy to code the generation of HTML codes according to visual appearance. I want to know if there is any class or library for implementing this?

I actually can create a gui like the following image but I can't generate HTML code according to it.
[image]

Comment: Check [HTMLEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html)

Comment: You might be looking for a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: @Stefan but can i use it inside my java application?

Comment: What kind of MVC are you using?

Comment: sorry.what MVC means?a ide?i'm using net beans